# Typecasting Member Variable Pointer to Object Pointer

Tags: c++, casting

I want to know if typecasting a member variable to object pointer is okay to do in C++?

I have a class as follows -

```
class Foo
{
private:
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;

public
    void func1(...);
    void func2(...);
    void func3(...);
}
```

In addition I have a 3rd party code, which has a callback as -

```
void callbackFunction (int *xPointer)
{
     // This is what I want to do
     Foo * fooPtr = (Foo*)xPointer;
     if(fooPtr->y == fooPtr->z)
     {
          //... do something
     }
}
```

In this code, the `xPointer` variable points to int x of my class object.
Now, I want to know can I somehow typecast `xPointer` to `Foo *`. In C, I typecasted the pointer to struct pointer to access other member, without any problem.

Is there any danger involving such typecast in case of C++?

If it is a problem, then how can I get pointer to object using the pointer to its member variable?

Thank You

Comment: How are you going to cast `xPointer` if its in third-party code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to work directly with class pointers to obtain pointers to their members you must make sure that the class is a [POD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure) type. Otherwise there could be hidden members (like a [vtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)) or paddings that would break any effort.

To know it you should try with [`std::is_pod<Foo>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pod) which is a convenience trait class that will tell you if the class has a standard layout.

In any case it sounds like you should avoid this approach, since it seems inherently unsafe. Why can't you just pass the pointer to the member variable? Eg:

```
Foo myFoo;
cllabackFunction(&(myFoo.x));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I indeed pass the pointer as you mentioned in the callback function. however I want to access `myFoo.y` in the callback function. For that I need the pointer to `myFoo`

Answer (score 1):

This doesnt entirely strike me as a thing you really want to be doing. Still,

There is the `offsetof (type,member)` macro, it returns the byte offset of a field within your struct. You can use that to get the base address of the object (from the address of one of its members - if you know which member) and cast that address to the correct type.

of course, its not guaranteed to work for non-PODS, although not guaranteed doesn't mean it wont work, your ok with non-portable and potentially undefined behaviour aren't you?